# When button is clicked (tkinter), nothing is returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, encryption

When I run this no errors come up, but the button does not return anything

```
import tkinter
#imports the tkinter module

window = tkinter.Tk()
#creates window
window.geometry("675x300")
#sets window size
window.configure(background="#66FFFF")
#sets window background
window.title("Vigenere Cipher")
#Window title
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
#window logo
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="vigciph12.gif")
#imports photo
w = tkinter.Label(window, image=photo)
#puts photo in window
w.pack()

lblInst = tkinter.Label(window, text="Encrypt Message Below.", bg="#66FFFF", font=("Helvetica", 16))
#Adds title
lblInst.pack()

lblphrase = tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter phrase to be encrypted:", bg="#66FFFF", font=("Helvetica", 10))
#tells user to enter phrase

phrases = str()
phrase = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable = phrases )
```

#######adds box for user to submit reply##############(I suspect this may be the root of the problem)

```
lblphrase.pack()
phrase.pack()

lblkeyphrase = tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter keyword:", bg="#66FFFF", font=("Helvetica", 10))

keyphrases = str()
keyphrase = tkinter.Entry(textvariable = keyphrases)
```

##adds box for user to submit reply#########(I suspect this may be the root of the problem)

```
lblkeyphrase.pack()
keyphrase.pack()


def keyword_cipher(key, phrase):

            if len(phrase) > len(key):
                while len(phrase) > len(key):
                    length_to_add = len(phrase) - len(key)
                    key = key + key[0:length_to_add]
                    #adds words together so phrase is long enough

            elif len(phrase) < len(key):
                while len(phrase) < len(key):
                    length_to_sub = len(key) - (len(key) - len(phrase))
                    key = key[0:length_to_sub]


            else:
                pass

            #shift the characters
            shifted_phrase = ''
            for i in range(len(phrase)):
                new_letter = (ord(key[i]) - 96) + (ord(phrase[i]) - 96) + 96
                if new_letter > 122:
                    new_letter = chr(new_letter - 26)

                else:
                    new_letter = chr(new_letter)


                shifted_phrase = shifted_phrase + new_letter
            return shifted_phrase

            #shifts letters


            lbl.configure(text = (shifted_phrase))

            lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text="Nothing Yet", bg="#66FFFF", font=("Helvetica", 10))
            lbl.pack()
```

##############This could be the problem

```
def lol():
    keyword_cipher(keyphrases, phrases)




btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Submit", fg="#66FFFF", bg="#383a39",command=lol())
btn.pack()



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8269096/3001761 or dozens of others...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Button's command executed immediately when I create the Button, and not when I click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-my-buttons-command-executed-immediately-when-i-create-the-button-and-no)

Answer (score 1):

```
tkinter.Button(window, text="Submit", fg="#66FFFF", bg="#383a39",command=lol())
#                                                                           ↑↑
```

This makes the `lol` function execute immediately. So what you pass as the keyword argument to the `tkinter.Button` call is the return value of `lol()`. So instead of `lol` being the command that is executed when you click the button, the return value of `lol()` is used as the command.

But `lol()` doesn’t return anything:

```
def lol():
    keyword_cipher(keyphrases, phrases)
```

So there is no command bound to the button at all. Instead, pass the function itself:

```
tkinter.Button(…, command=lol)
```

Because there are no parentheses, it’s not called immediately. So the function is used as the command callback.

Note that you should do something with the return value of `keyword_cipher()`. For example show it somewhere in the UI.