# Why do these two programs using tkinter to create grids of widgets perform differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been fiddling with this snippet for producing a grid of tkinter Entry widgets. When I write the code like this, it works as intended:

```
import tkinter as tk

rows = []
for i in range(5):
    cols = []
    for j in range(4):
        e = tk.Entry()
        e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")
        e.insert("end", '%d.%d' % (i, j))
        cols.append(e)
    rows.append(cols)

def onPress():
    for row in rows:
        for col in row:
            print (col.get())


tk.Button(text='Fetch', command=onPress).grid()
tk.mainloop()
```

But if its like this, it runs the command "onPress" before the button is pressed:

```
import tkinter as tk
def entries():
    rows = []
    for i in range(5):
        cols = []
        for j in range(4):
            e = tk.Entry()
            e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")
            e.insert("end", '%d.%d' % (i, j))
            cols.append(e)
        rows.append(cols)
    return rows

def onPress(rows):
    for row in rows:
        for col in row:
            print (col.get())

entries()
tk.Button(text='Fetch', command=onPress(entries())).grid()
tk.mainloop()
```

Why is this happening? It looks to me like these should be equivalent. I'm a beginner, so I'm probably missing something very obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8269096/953482)

Answer (score 0):

`onPress(entries())` in `tk.Button(text='Fetch', command=onPress(entries()))` *calls* `onPress` immediately, but `command=onPress` in `tk.Button(text='Fetch', command=onPress)` passes a function called `onPress` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you! so is this a situation where lambda: would be used?

Comment: This depends on what you're trying to do. Anyways, `command` must be a callable. `lambda: onPress(entries())` _is_ a callable.