# Tkinter unexpected behavior

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a set of methods in my program the use Tkinter that don't behave like I thought they would. I want to be able to push a button in the window and have more text fields appear, and be able to return a list of the results in the text fields. Here is what I have:

```
def expandChoice(self):
    root = Tk()

    choices = []

    plusButton = Button (root, text='+', command=self.addChoice(root, choices)) 
    plusButton.pack()

    quitButton = Button (root, text='Ok', command=root.destroy ) 
    quitButton.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    return choices

def addChoice(self, parent, variables):

    variables.append(StringVar())

    text = Entry(parent, textvariable=variables[len(variables)-1])
    text.pack()
```

What happens is that one text field appears when the window loads (above the buttons), and the plus button does nothing. What am I doing wrong? It seems like the addChoice method get called automatically when the first button's constructor is called and then doesn't work after that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter button command activates upon running program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704568/tkinter-button-command-activates-upon-running-program)

Answer (score 0):

The `command` option takes a reference to a callable. You, however, are calling `addChoice` immediately, then assigning what that retuns (None) to the `command` option.

You need to do something like `Button(...command=self.addChoice)`

If you need to pass arguments you will need to either use a lambda or `functools.partial`. Search for either of those on this site -- variations of this question has been asked and answered many times on SO.