# Tkinter button command activates when program is run

Tags: python, tkinter, destroy

Found a similar thread here: [Tkinter button command activates upon running program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704568/tkinter-button-command-activates-upon-running-program)

However I couldn't fully understand the answer being a relatively new.

```
def Destroy(var):
    var.destroy()
```

Is the function I wish too call.

```
exit_button = tk.Button(master, text = "Exit", command = Destroy(master))
```

However when I run the program, it instantly closes with the error message:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command:  application has been destroyed
```

What I want is for the program to exit once the button is pressed, and I will be using the same function to destroy other widgets etc so it needs to be a function.

Will clarify more if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define `exit_button` you're actually calling `Destroy` so you need to pass a function or lambda to prevent passing a function call.

```
exit_button = tk.Button(master, text = "Exit", command = lambda: Destroy(master))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you think you could explain more about lambda's? I've never encountered them before. Or link me to a good explanation.

Comment: Lambdas are short functions that are great for passing snippets like the one above. Basically, in your code you actually destroy the master, whereas in my code you pass a function that will destroy the master.

Comment: Do you understand it now?

Comment: Here's a link if you need more clarification on what a [lambda](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/) is.

Comment: Is my code working for you?