# Tkinter Key binding doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a button that increases money or something, but i am just trying to test it out in another project

This is my code for the button

```py
global counterCheck
counterCheck = 0



def checkClick():
    global counterCheck
    counterCheck += 1
    textClick.config(text=counterCheck)


bttt = Button(root, width=1720, height=600, text="Click Here", command=checkClick)

bttt.bind("<space>", checkClick())
bttt.pack()
```

Comment: With `bttt.bind("<space>", checkClick())` you bind the _result_ of the function call to the event, not the function itself.

Comment: However, that's actually not the only problem. For `bind`, the function also has to accept an argument, and by binding the event to the button, the button needs to have focus, and in that case it will be triggered on space anyway.

Comment: Ive added an answer, do mark it as the answer, if it helped, to close the Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually multiple problems with your code. The first one is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3704568/1639625), but there is more:

- you execute the function and then bind the result of that function, which is `None`, to the event; instead, you have to bind the function itself
- also, unlike with `Button.command`, when a function is called via `bind`, it will get an parameter, the event that triggered it
- by binding the key to the Button, it will only be registered when the button has focus (e.g. when pressing Tab until the button is "highlighted")
- and the button already *has* a binding to be "clicked" when it is focused and Space is pressed, so adding another binding would make it react twice

I actually did not manage to `unbind` the "press on space-key" action from the Button, so one workaround (besides never giving the button the focus) would be to use a different key, e.g. `Return`, and bind that to `root` or use `bind_all` so it is bound to all widgets.

```
def checkClick(*unused): # allow optional unused parameters
    ...

root.bind("<Return>", checkClick) # function itself, no (), root, and Return
```

After this, there are three ways to trigger the button:

- by clicking it, calling the `command`
- by focusing it and pressing space, emulating a click
- by pressing the `Return` key, calling the key event binding